# How to get running pod status via Rest API

Tags: kubernetes

Any idea how to get a POD status via Kubernetes REST API for a POD with known name?
I can do it via kubectl by just typing "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces" since the output lists STATUS as a separate column but not sure which REST API to use to get the STATUS of a running pod.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can just query the API server:

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer [REDACTED]" \
https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/pods
```

If you want to get the status you can pipe them through something like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer [REDACTED]" \ 
https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/pods \
| jq '.items[] | .metadata.name + " " + .status.phase'
```

Comment: Thank you.  We create the pods by issuing API call to replication controllers so the actual pod name is replication controller name plus ...XYZ...  Yes, the output can be filtered as you suggested.  Will do for now,  Thanks again

Comment: this `.status.phase` shows status as running though pods are in crashloopbackoff

Comment: github issue for same-
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/76619

Answer (score 3):

When not sure which REST API and the command is known, run the command as below with -v9 option. Note the kubectl supports only a subset of options in imperative way (get, delete, create etc), so it's better to get familiar with the REST API.

> kubectl -v9 get pods

The above will output the REST API call. This can be modified appropriately and the output can piped to jq to get subset of the data.